# UNIX script to read data from text file

Tags: unix

I have a text file which contains below data:

```
Name: ABC
Place: XYZ123
Email: def@123.com
```

In this case I only want to read the data "AFTER COLON".
i.e. I want to read `ABC`, `XYZ123`, `def@123.com`

Can you guide me achieving this?

Comment: What do you mean with read? To print or to store into a variable or...? There are many approaches to this.

Comment: I want to store it into variable and then use them..

Comment: But use them all together or keep reading the file and using the value while looping? That is, give more context of your general problem.

Comment: Why don't you show us the script you've written to consume the variables, and we can help you fix the part where you read them in? Also, UNIX isn't a scripting language, you probably want to take this with the actual language you intend to use, such as [tag:bash].

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
MYVAR=$(cat $1 | cut -d":" -f2)
echo $MYVAR
```

This uses cat to pipe the entire text file to cut, which uses your desired delimiter - in this case ":", to grab the text to the right of the colon.  It then stores it into MYVAR, displayed by echo.